# Weird US keyboard input on Macbook Pro with French keyboard layout?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, keyboard, internationalization

I've been given a replacement Macbook Pro while waiting for my new one to arrive, and the machine has a French Keyboard layout (I work for a French institution, and the technical service did not have any replacement machine with a US keyboard).

I would like to switch to the US layout I am very used to, especially to get easy access to curly brackets and tilde signs I sue to program. I changed the keyboard settings and almost all keys do what they should, apart for the top left "tilde" key (the key below the ESC key), that is mapped to an unexpected sign in all US layouts I tried (US, US international, US-PC).

I attach a screenshot of the weird US keyboard layout I'm proposed. The machine is running OS X 10.10.5. How can I set a standard US layout?

Thanks, M.

[image: weird US keyboard layout]

Answer (score 1):

Update: after a few tests I came to the conclusion the system is proposing me the US International layout even if I explicitly select US. Is there any way to remap a the keyboard to act like a real US layout?

Comment: The "real US layout" is designed for an ANSI keyboard, which has one less key than the ISO keyboard used in France. To get the tilde key where you want (instead of on the key next to the Z) I think you will have to make a custom layout with Ukelele or Karabiner.